# NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN strongswan ipsec tunnel

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

Hi I am trying to setup site-to-site vpn tunneling on AWS VMs. Below are my `ipsec.conf` files for both VMs.

```
VM-1 (assume IP address : 1.2.3.4)

 conn %default
    lifetime=60m
    mobike=no
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    type=transport
    auto=start

conn gateway-1
    left=1.2.3.4
    leftid=1.2.3.4
    leftfirewall=yes
    right=1.2.4.5
    rightid=1.2.4.5
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    leftauth=secret
    rightauth=secret
    type=transport
    auto=start


VM-2 (assume IP address : 1.2.3.5)
 conn %default
    lifetime=60m
    mobike=no
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    type=transport
    auto=start

conn gateway-2
    left=1.2.3.5
    leftid=1.2.3.5
    leftfirewall=yes
    right=1.2.4.4
    rightid=1.2.4.4
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    leftauth=secret
    rightauth=secret
    type=transport
    auto=start
```

on both machines I have started strongswan by `strongswan start` command.

When I am trying to run `strongswan up gateway-1` from VM-1 I am getting -

```
initiating IKE_SA aaa[3] to 1.2.3.5
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP)    N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 1.2.3.4[500] to 1.2.3.5[500] (336 bytes)
received packet: from 1.2.3.5[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (36 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
establishing connection 'gateway-1' failed
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: If VM2 is using 1.2.3.5 as its IP address as well as its IKE ID, why isn't VM1 configured to accept that – why does it have right[id]=1.2.4.5 instead?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please give some example. I new to this. What is IKE ID?

Answer (score 0):

IKE proposals are first matched by the initiator and responder IDs (IDi/IDr), which work a lot like TLS SNI or the HTTP Host header – the initiator says "I'm <leftid> and I want to speak with <rightid>" and the responder tries to find a configuration **matching these IDs** (either as leftid/rightid or as rightid/leftid).

But currently your defined connections have IDs that do not match each other at all – e.g. VM2 claims to be `1.2.3.5`, yet VM1 is configured to ask for `1.2.4.5` for some reason:

```
VM 1                          VM 2
-------------------           -------------------
conn gateway-1                conn gateway-2
    leftid=1.2.3.4       /--     leftid=1.2.3.5
    rightid=1.2.4.5   --/        rightid=1.2.4.4
```

(Note that the IDs are used for matching only, so they don't actually need to be in IP address format – it may be easier to understand this if you use domain-format IDs, e.g. `leftid=gateway1.example.com`.)

---

Note that strongSwan no longer recommends the ipsec.conf style; you should take the opportunity to rewrite this for swanctl instead.

Comment: Thank you for detailed information. With `swanctl` how can I start the service, like `strongswan start`? How can I install `strongswan.swanctl.service`

Comment: Depends on distro, e.g. on Arch it used to be `strongswan-swanctl.service` (but then it got renamed to regular strongswan.service), on Debian it's in a "charon-systemd" package, etc. Migration from ipsec.conf to swanctl is not required, but I would still recommend it as the swanctl config files can be easier to understand.

Comment: As another note, modp1024 (i.e. 1024-bit DH) is considered quite weak nowadays. If traditional DH is needed then use _at least_ modp2048 (preferably modp3072), however, strongSwan supports ECDH, so ecp256 or curve25519 are much better choices.